# delete MailBox in exchange server 2019

Tags: exchange-server

i have exchange server 2019 i delete the user from active Directory users but the mailbox is still On the disk I mean, the space saved on the disk shows that the mailbox is still there And I want the mailbox to be deleted from the server, but I think that because I deleted the user before deleting the mailbox, this problem has arisen and I cannot delete this mailbox.

I tried to find this mailbox in the list by following commands but it was not found

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
```

If possible, explain what happens to the mailbox when the user is deleted and what is the correct way to delete the user and the mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

When a user is deleted from AD with a mailbox assigned, the mailbox becomes a **Disconnected mailbox**

Disabled and deleted mailboxes are retained in the mailbox database until the deleted mailbox retention period expires, which is 30 days by default.

You can check if the mailbox still exists via PowerShell:

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity <identity>
```

If you want to permanently delete the mailbox without waiting for the retention period you can use following command:

```
Remove-Mailbox -Identity <identity> -Permanent $true
```

Comment: when i use Remove Command i got this error
Active Directory operation failed on ADS.local. This error is not retriable. Additional information: Access is denied.